# Ruby's open-uri open method working

Tags: ruby, scripting, proxy

Here is an weird situation, hope you can help me with a reason:

```
require "open-uri"

class TraceParser
  def starttorip
    url = 'http://yahoo.com'
    proxy_addr = 'http://my proxy server:'
    proxy_port = 1010
    begin
      open(url, :proxy => (proxy_addr + proxy_port.to_s)) do |source|
        source.each_line do |x|
          puts x
        end
      end
    end
  end
  varb = TraceParser.new
  varb.starttorip
end
```

Above code works like a charm, and everything is rosy. But, when I change the proxy definition to something like this:

```
require "open-uri"
class TraceParser
  def starttorip
    url = 'http://yahoo.com'
    begin
      open (url, :proxy => 'http://my proxy server:1010') do |source|
        source.each_line do |x|
          puts x
        end
      end
    end
  end
  varb = TraceParser.new
  varb.starttorip
end
```

Everything breaks loose:

```
/tracerparser.rb:6: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')' (SyntaxError)
      open (url, :proxy => "my proxy server...
```

From what I understand, the first one is splitting proxy defn into two strings and appending to the open gem. Thanks for sharing your inputs.

Comment: Don't put spaces in between a method name and it's opening '('

Comment: wouldn't it better be to start the rip from outside the class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the space after the `open`, it has nothing to do with the proxy map entry.